# How to attach XML file to Web Service

Tags: .net, wcf

I have to write a .net SOAP web service either it might be ASP.Net Web Service (or) WCF web service. When caller receives the web service response, it should have a xml attachment along with SOAP body. So the Android application will download the XML file on the device. My worry is how to attach XML file to WCF service or ASP.Net webservice. It is better provide me idea in both WCF and ASP.Net.

If possible provide me with an example (or) any link which talk about that. The reason I am asking is, I am new to web service attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go to send attachment with WCF

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/08/29/sending-attachments-with-wcf.aspx